# Oracle search problem with Georgian symbols

Tags: sql, oracle, unicode, plsql, symbols

I have table with unicode data like 'საქართველო'.

When I execute this statement ... `

```
select * from table t 
where t.column = 'საქართველო';
```

... it returns no data/value.

Whereas if I create a function

```
create or replace function my_fnc (p_column in varchar2) 
  return sys_refcursor
is
  v_result is sys_refcursor;
begin
  open v_result for 
      select * from table t where t.column = p_column;
  return v_result;
end my_fnc;
```

it returns values.

Can you help me in this case?

Comment: Just to be clear, can you edit your question to show how you execute the function?

Comment: as i know there are some ways to execute execute it manually.
i run 'select my_fnc('საქართველო')from dual;'
it returns cursor and the second way, i run test in PL/SQL Developer and write into in parameters 'საქართველო'

Answer (score 2):

Try explicitly casting your string as `UNICODE`:

`where t.column = N'საქართველო'`

Comment: thanks, but it didn't works :(
with NSL_OPTIONS is everything OK